# Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake: rabbitmq using adonisjs 5 connection fail

Tags: adonisjs-ace

I'm using  **node 14.17.0** and **adonisjs 5.8.5.**

This is my rabbitmq .env :

```
RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME=localhost
RABBITMQ_USER=
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=
RABBITMQ_PORT=15672
RABBITMQ_PROTOCOL= 'amqp://'
```

I  try sendToQueue. But I get that's error. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the problem. Just change RABBITMQ_PORT=15672 become **RABBITMQ_PORT=5672**  It will passed.